# does the addfields aggregate field actually add fields to the collection?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation

I'm new to mongodb and aggregation.  Specifically have a question about https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-pipeline/

I am trying to create a pipeline where I have a need to create temporary variables to carry values from one stage to the next.  I believe the way you do this is to use the 'addFields' operator.  Does the addFields operator add these temporary fields to the collection?  If so, is there a way around it, as I don't want to store any derivative fields into the database.  I have no use for the temporary inter-stage fields after the aggregation operation is complete.

Comment: No it does not - unless you use `$merge` operator at the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the $[addfields](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/#behavior) documentation points out, The added fields only apply to the document in the context of the pipeline.

1. That means the original document is not modified
2. You can add $addfields at any point in the pipeline, deriving fields from the data in previous stages

Comment: Thanks for confirming it @Ravi.  I must have missed it.